# MendBolt Task in Azure DevOps not working

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, whitesource, whitesource-bolt

I have installed the free [MendBolt](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=whitesource.whiteSource-bolt-v2) extension in my ADO Organization.
I have also registered my account by going to **Organization Settings > Extension > Mend** and providing my details like Name, Email, and Company.

When I use MendBolt task in the pipeline, like following:

```
- task: WhiteSource@21
  inputs:
    cwd: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    projectName: 'projname'
  displayName: WhiteSource:Scan packages
```

I get the following error:

> **Unable to get Mend organization capabilities. Please reactivate the Mend extension by updating the activation key under Organization
> Settings > Extensions > Mend**

This is working in another ADO Organization without any error but not in my current ADO Org.

What is the reason? And how do I get this working?

Comment: I tested the extension in my two organizations, and it works in both organizations. Maybe you can uninstall and reinstall the extension, then try again.

Comment: Is it because the extension is installed by Org admin and activated by me and I don't have org admin rights?
Does it require to be activated by the same user who installed it?

Comment: I use another user account to activate the extension and it still works. Could you please check if the extension is [the free one](https://docs.mend.io/bundle/community_tools/page/mend_bolt_for_azure_pipelines.html)? I found another extension [Mend for Azure DevOps (formerly WhiteSource)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=whitesource.WhiteSource-azure-devops-services) which is a paid extension. The paid extension needs the activation key when [activate it](https://docs.mend.io/bundle/integrations/page/azure_devops_pipelines_integration.html#Activating-the-Extension).